# OS fingerprinting via TCP

Tags: ip, tcp, fingerprinting, os-fingerprinting

I have searched online about this topic and the only information I got is that TCP SYN/ACK can be used to know the type of the target OS. If that is true, I don't understand how this occurs? Does TCP handshaking lead to OS fingerprinting?

Comment: Have you read [OS Detection](https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html) from nmap?  They [wrote the book](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html) on it.

Comment: There's also the [`p0f`](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f3/) tool, which can provide some clues/ideas of how such fingerprinting can be done.

Answer (score 3):

OS detection goes a lot further, using all kind of data of the IP and TCP headers fields. If you're into reading, "Silence on the Wire" by Michal Zalewski addresses a lot on this topic.